# Display the output of a function on a Python GUI Calculator

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I have created a GUI calculator and would like to include an additional function "probate". The normal standard calculator portion of the GUI works fine however when I attempted to include the special function and click on the probate button in the GUI nothing happens. The code for part of the calculator is shown below. I have excluded many of the digits and operators of the calculator.

```
from tkinter import *
def click(num):
    global op
    op=op+str(num)
    iptext.set(op)
def evaluate():
    global op
    output = str(eval(op))
    iptext.set(output)

def clearDisplay():
    global op
    op=""
    iptext.set(op)

def probate(op):

    # global probate_fee
    VALUE_CATEGORY1 = 10000
    VALUE_CATEGORY2 = 250000
    RATE_CATEGORY1 = 0.05
    RATE_CATEGORY2 = 0.03
    RATE_CATEGORY3 = 0.01
    estate_worth=op

    if (estate_worth) < 0:
        # is_on = False
        print("Invalid Enrty")
    else:
        if (estate_worth <= VALUE_CATEGORY1):
            probate_fee = 500
        elif ((estate_worth > VALUE_CATEGORY1) & (estate_worth <= VALUE_CATEGORY2)):
            probate_fee = (estate_worth - VALUE_CATEGORY1) * RATE_CATEGORY2 + VALUE_CATEGORY1 * RATE_CATEGORY1
        elif (estate_worth > VALUE_CATEGORY2):
            probate_fee = (estate_worth - VALUE_CATEGORY2) * RATE_CATEGORY3 + (
                        (VALUE_CATEGORY2 - VALUE_CATEGORY1) * RATE_CATEGORY2) + VALUE_CATEGORY1 * RATE_CATEGORY1
        else:
            print("Invalid Entry")
    return str(probate_fee)

calc=Tk()
calc.title("GUI Calculator")
op=""
iptext=StringVar()
iparea=Entry(calc,font=('large,_font',15,'bold'),bd=10,justify="right",insertwidth=4,textvariable=iptext).grid(columnspan=10)
bt7=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(7),bg="lavender",text="7",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=0)
bt8=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(8),bg="lavender",text="8",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=1)
bt9=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(9),bg="lavender",text="9",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=2)
add=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click('+'),bg="lavender",text="+",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=3)
eql=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=evaluate,bg="lavender",text="=",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=2)
div=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click('/'),bg="lavender",text="/",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=3)
btC=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=clearDisplay,bg="lavender",text="C",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=1)
btprobate = Button(calc, font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), command=lambda: evaluate, bg="lavender", text="probate", bd=5, padx=0,
                 pady=10).grid(columnspan=10)

calc.mainloop(),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing happens is that you need to include "()" after the function name for btprobate.  E.g.:

```
btprobate = Button(calc, font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), command=lambda: evaluate(), bg="lavender", text="probate", bd=5, padx=0,
                 pady=10).grid(columnspan=10)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but here's a stab at code that functions as requested in the comments (it runs, the probate button does stuff):

```
from tkinter import *
def click(num):
    global op
    op=op+str(num)
    iptext.set(op)
def evaluate():
    global op
    output = str(eval(op))
    iptext.set(output)

def clearDisplay():
    global op
    op=""
    iptext.set(op)

def probate(op):

    # global probate_fee
    VALUE_CATEGORY1 = 10000
    VALUE_CATEGORY2 = 250000
    RATE_CATEGORY1 = 0.05
    RATE_CATEGORY2 = 0.03
    RATE_CATEGORY3 = 0.01
    estate_worth=eval(op)

    if (estate_worth) < 0:
        # is_on = False
        print("Invalid Enrty")
    else:
        if (estate_worth <= VALUE_CATEGORY1):
            probate_fee = 500
        elif ((estate_worth > VALUE_CATEGORY1) & (estate_worth <= VALUE_CATEGORY2)):
            probate_fee = (estate_worth - VALUE_CATEGORY1) * RATE_CATEGORY2 + VALUE_CATEGORY1 * RATE_CATEGORY1
        elif (estate_worth > VALUE_CATEGORY2):
            probate_fee = (estate_worth - VALUE_CATEGORY2) * RATE_CATEGORY3 + (
                        (VALUE_CATEGORY2 - VALUE_CATEGORY1) * RATE_CATEGORY2) + VALUE_CATEGORY1 * RATE_CATEGORY1
        else:
            print("Invalid Entry")
        iptext.set(str(probate_fee))
        
    # return str(probate_fee)

calc=Tk()
calc.title("GUI Calculator")
op=""
iptext=StringVar()
iparea=Entry(calc,font=('large,_font',15,'bold'),bd=10,justify="right",insertwidth=4,textvariable=iptext).grid(columnspan=10)
bt7=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(7),bg="lavender",text="7",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=0)
bt8=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(8),bg="lavender",text="8",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=1)
bt9=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click(9),bg="lavender",text="9",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=2)
add=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click('+'),bg="lavender",text="+",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=1,column=3)
eql=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=evaluate,bg="lavender",text="=",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=2)
div=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda:click('/'),bg="lavender",text="/",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=3)
btC=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=clearDisplay,bg="lavender",text="C",bd=5,padx=15,pady=10).grid(row=4,column=1)
btP=Button(calc,font=('arial',15,'bold'),command=lambda: probate(op), bg="lavender", text="probate", bd=5, padx=0, pady=10).grid(columnspan=10)

calc.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt but unfortunately that does not appear to be the correct solution. Nothing happens when I tried that. Also note that the "eql" does not have this bracket but it does work fine. Its just the "btprobate" does not work. The "probate" function itself works well but I am not able to display the output of the function on the calculator when the "Probate" button is clicked.

Comment: Hmm, that's unexpected since that does fix the issue for me (original does not work). I saw that you hadn't used "()" on your eql button, but I tried anyway to see if it would work.

Comment: If I using the  command=lambda: evaluate() in the "btprobate" as you suggested that means that somewhere in the evaluate function I would need to call on the probate function when the probate button is clicked. The evaluate function would therefore have 2 main purposes. 1) To perform normal calculator functions and 2) to call on the probate function whenever the probate button is clicked.

Comment: I understand that, but you asked, "... click on the probate button in the GUI nothing happens."  I was answering why the probate button did nothing.  If you want the probate button to run the probate function, then you need to replace "evaluate" with "probate(op)" in the lambda function.  You'll get an error as probate() expects 'op' to be a number, not a string, but that solves your problem of "nothing happens"

Comment: By chance anyone show me, by displaying the correct code, how i can make my GUI calculator work smoothly without errors?

Comment: @Marlon See edited answer